# Doctype Problems

Tags: html, doctype

I have problems, to set the correct Doc Type. Please have a look at my code above. it returns an error in the w3org validator.
Where is the error?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<html dir="ltr" lang="de-DE" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
<head>
```

I found the solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but you've got *two* `<html>` tags (I think you're only allowed one. And you're using an `html` doctype, with an xml namespace, I think.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this? What is your goal?

Comment: @David — it is the multiple HTML elements that causes the error reported by the validator. You should make that an answer.

Comment: @Pekka — I'd guess "Write a Facebook app".

Comment: @David Yep, I need the open grapf meta data in the header.

Comment: @Pekka I need to embed the open Graph Meta and want to have a valid doc type.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @David Dorward, posting comment as an answer.

The `<html>` element is the [root-element of the `html` document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#edef-HTML), and as such can only appear once in a valid html document. For the purposes of validity you could either just remove one of the `<html>` opening tags (and, if you have two `</html>` closing tags remove one of those too), or combine all the attributes into one and then remove the *empty* `html` tag (which isn't much of a difference to the previous option, really).

Also, but as an addenda, I'm unsure as to the use of the xml namespaces within an html document; given that it passed without comment, except for my own, in the comments to your question it's *probably* alright; but it...feels wrong. Which is about the worst explanation for anything I've ever put on this site. And I feel ashamed for it.

Comment: Okay. And how can I embed the open graph data, to get a valid document?

Comment: @Lars: honestly, I have no idea. But that *is* a separate question from the one you asked here. This comment might sound glib, but I genuinely am sorry that I can't help with that part of the problem. :(

Comment: @Lars: excellent! ...isn't that what I suggested in my answer?

Comment: @David — yes, it is. @Lars — you should [accept this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).